# How can I get rid of a URL in a fetch (to use kind of a variable instead)?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have this function for submitting code (see gist https://gist.github.com/constantinscum/4ed753dcd681b4758a8500e4b53d925c) and I don't want to write that //https: in every source file. I was thinking about a global variable but it might be a more elegant solution for this. Do you have any idea how to do that?
I want to get rid of the localhost domain URL because it will change after the app will be deployed on a server.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the request without the `http://localhost:3000` part. It will still find it. Try and let me know if it works.

I noticed you added the React tag to your question.
If your back-end and front-end are running on different ports you have to setup a proxy in your front-end `package.json` file. It would look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/api",
  "dependencies": {...},
  ...
}
```

Now you can `fetch("/code/add")` for example and if react does not find that route defined on the front-end it will look in proxy routes and do this by itself: `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/code/add")`

Answer (score 3):

Probably this will not give a direct answer to your question, but its a good practice,

What we normally do is create a separate file for api details

for ex:

api.js

```
  //REACT_APP_SERVER_URL is a env variable in .env file
  const rootUri = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
    ? process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
    : 'http://localhost:3001';

  const apiVersion = 'v1';
  const apiBasePath = `${rootUri}/api/${apiVersion}`; //this is the base path

  export const userApis = {
    all: {
      url: `${apiBasePath}/users`,
      method: 'GET',
    },
    update: {
      url: `${apiBasePath}/user`,
      method: 'POST',
    },
  };
```

this is how we use it

```
const fetchAllUser = () => {
    const api = userApis.all;
    fetch(api.url, {
        method: api.url.method,
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    }...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a proxy to the backend api url, this will allow you to just write the api url without adding server name / domaine

in development you can create `setupProxy.js` and use [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) to redirect all api calls to the server

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3001',
      changeOrigin: true,
    }),
  );
};
```

and your fetch call will look something like this

```
 fetch('/api/code/add')
```

you can read more about setup proxy [Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

and for production it will depend on the tools you will use, (Nginx, Node, ...)